# getting a single record from a Sharepoint list

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to get a single record from a SharePoint list however I am getting a RED X, I have passed though the ID of the item however which is working for the main form I am using on the page.

My statement is below, the list is called contacts which power apps is aware of and autocompleted

```
First(Filter(contacts.contacttype, ID=selectID))
```

also tried

```
First(contacts.contacttype)
```

which I would expect to just return the contacttype of the first record in the list.

Am I missing somthing really silly

Comment: also tried First(Filter(contacts.contacttype, contacts.ID = selectID))

Comment: also trying LookUp(contacts.contacttype, ID=selectID) this seems to be the better way to do it still no luck tho

Answer (score 0):

Assuming contacts is the name of the list, and contacttype is a field on the list, you will need to get the record before you reference the field.

To do this in one line:

```
First(contacts).contacttype
```

Or as multiple lines, saving the record to a variable:

```
Set(varContact,First(contacts))
varContact.contacttype
```

Comment: This is not working and I can't for the life of me see why because I am pretty sure it should

Comment: @TomBruton if you hover over the error, what does it say?

Comment: How is the column name displayed in sharepoint? Does .'Contact Type' work instead of .contacttype?

Comment: contacttype is a multiple choice field in sharepoint. First(contacts).contacttype
 which is just a text field does work

Comment: its doesnt say there is any error but red a red cross next to it